# Manipulating an uploaded svg file in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg, carrierwave

I am building a rails app that uses [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to let a user upload svg files and [Inline_SVG](https://github.com/jamesmartin/inline_svg) to display them inline in my views. I need to be able to upload files of any size and then resize and rotate them according to specifications.

If these were png's or jpegs ImageMagick could do it, but it doesn't handle svgs.

I tried to change the attributes using javascript to resize, but it does not solve my issue, and I have no idea how that would work to rotate them anyways:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var img;
  var images = $('svg');
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    img = images[i];
    img.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 1000 1000');
    img.removeAttribute('height');
    img.removeAttribute('width');
  }
</script>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are like xml files (text files) so you should be editing those SVG's directly or on the fly in your rails application. Follow this tutorial if you wish to do transformation(https://www.alt-soft.com/tutorial/svg_tutorial/svg_transform.html)